# How to wait on multiple PromiseKit promises which have a different payload?

Tags: ios, swift, generics, promisekit

In my project, I have numerous functions which asynchronously fetch data from the underlying data source and return result as a `Promise<T>`, where `T` is an *optional* model object.
I need to fetch 2 *different*, independent objects in parallel. For that I've tried to use `when(resolved: [Promise<T>])` function:

```
let userPromise: Promise<User> = fetchUser(with: userID)
let documentPromise: Promise<Document> = fetchDocument(with: documentID)

when(resolved: [userPromise, documentPromise]).done {
...
}
```

But I'm getting an error `Cannot invoke 'when' with an argument list of type '(resolved: [Any])'`. I've tried to assign promises to explicitly declared array:

`let promises: [Promise<Any>] = [userPromise, documentPromise]`

but now I'm getting an error that `Promise<User>` cannot be assigned to `Promise<Any>`. Frankly, I can't wrap my mind around it. What's the problem there?

**P.S.** To make things easier to grasp, I have created the following snippet:

```
func getPromise() -> Promise<String> {
   return Promise<String>.pending().promise
}

let promise: Promise<Any> = getPromise()
```

which produces the similar error: `Cannot convert value of type 'Promise<String>' to specified type 'Promise<Any>'`
Any ideas how to solve it? Thanks!

**Environment:** PromiseKit 6.2.4, Swift 4.1, Xcode 9.4

Comment: Have you find an answer to this?

Comment: Nope, unfortunately.

Comment: Actually, I have. you can try: __PMKWhen([AnyPromise.init(try fetchUser(with: userID)), try AnyPromise.init(fetchDocument(with: documentID))])

Comment: Interesting! Thanks. Will try it out.

Answer (score 7):

`when(resolved:)` is declared so that it only accepts promises with the same type. Here's its signature:

```
public func when<T>(resolved promises: Promise<T>...)
```

Do you particularly need a non-rejecting `when(resolved:)`? Have you tried `when(fulfilled:_:)`? The difference is that the latter rejects as soon as one of the provided promises rejects.

If using `when(fullfilled:_:)` is possible then you could write something like this:

```
when(fulfilled: [userPromise, documentPromise])
  .done { user, document in
    // ...
  }
  .catch { error in
    // either of promises has been rejected
    print(error)
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Dan! :)  

`public func when<T>(resolved promises: Promise<T>...)` - yeah, that's why I have tried to upcast `Promise<User>` to `Promise<Any>`, which is a valid upcast AFAIK, but it doesn't work for some reason   

As to `when(fulfilled:_:)` option - it has exactly the same signature as `when(resolved:_:)`, so it doesn't work in my case as well...

Comment: @Serzhas nope, "resolved" version of `when` function has the following signature: `when<T>(resolved promises: Promise<T>...) -> Guarantee<[Result<T>]>` whereas "fulfilled" version is this one: `when<U, V>(fulfilled pu: U, _ pv: V) -> Promise<(U.T, V.T)> where U : Thenable, V : Thenable`. Notice the difference: `resolved` accepts a variadic parameter which is the same as passing an array with items of the same type. On the other hand, `fulfilled` accepts two parameters of possibly but not necessary different types.

Comment: Thanks, Dan! I will try "fulfilled" version with variadic parameter :)

Comment: Dan, would be great if you could change your array of two comments to a variadic array - your answer with that would have gone smoothly, I spent a lot of time using the code above as an example before changing successfully to variadic parameters.